# firebase functions and external API

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.apiResponse = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const url = "https://test-proj-heroku.herokuapp.com/api/plans"
const https = require('https');
  var req = https.get(url, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk; });
    resp.on('end', () => {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        response.send({ fulfillmentText: "Firebase  API Is Running..." });
      });
    }).on("error", (err) => { console.log("Error: " + err.message); });
});
```

Why this cloud function is not responding? Deploed on this URL = 
https://us-central1-ayyanalee-e891b.cloudfunctions.net/apiResponse.

Comment: Any errors in your cloud function logs? Are you on a paid Firebase plan? (you can't query non-google services if you aren't on a paid plan)

Comment: This is my cloud function logs: https://screenshots.firefox.com/9qOFCXf36w8lkprL/console.firebase.google.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to make a request to your Heroku server (*a non-Google product*) and it appears that you are on the free tier of Firebase. As [the pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) indicates, under the Cloud Functions portion section, free-tiers are only permitted to make Outbound Networking actions (*such as the call to your Heroku server*) to other Google services (*such as Gmail, Google Drive, etc...*)

If you want to make requests to your Heroku server, you'll need to upgrade to a paid Firebase tier.

Comment: does that mean this service has charges for each call?

Comment: not necessarily. It depends on how much you use the service. There are limits determined by Google Firebase.

Comment: Even Google reCAPTCHA v3 is not allowed in the Google Cloud Functions despite still **google.com**. [See my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61651415/verifying-recaptcha-v3-in-firebase-function-causes-cors-issue).