# Access external API from Firebase Hosted React App Created Using CRA

Tags: reactjs, firebase, api, cors, create-react-app

I have a React app(CRA) which is hosted on Firebase and am trying to access an external Rest API(using javascript's `fetch()` ) , but as that API is not on the same domain as the web-app , it throws a "CORS" error. The API has the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as `*` .
I can work this around using a proxy in `package.json` in development mode , but nothing seems to work after the app is hosted.

Have tried the below things

- Updated `Firebase.json` to include headers
- `no-cors` mode while using `fetch()`

Answer (score 2):

The proper CORS header is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, not `Access-Control-Origin`. Also, depending on the nature of the request you may need a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) and may not be able to use `*` as the origin.

There is nothing you can do on the client side to bypass CORS -- it is expressly designed as a browser security mechanism to prevent unexpected cross-domain requests. If you have control of the API server, you should be able to fix this. If you don't, you may need to use a Cloud Function to proxy requests to the external API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mis-spelled the header value(will edit the question). I have also tried creating a cloud function and tried to access it as a "rewrite" , but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Using cloud functions is the way to go here if Asker doesn't have control over the API, as Answerer said. Problem is, Firebase doesn't allow external API requests unless you're on a paid plan - so consider that when troubleshooting such requests in Firebase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123462/firebase-functions-and-external-api

Comment: Is europe-west-1 region not supported for function rewrites ? @michael bleigh

Comment: Only `us-central1` is supported for Cloud Functions rewrites at the moment. [Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run) rewrites support all production regions of Cloud Run.